# I have date stored in varchar in SQL Server as '19-09-2020' and I want to convert it to '2020-09-19'

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime

I have date stored in a `varchar` column in SQL Server as '19-09-2020'.

I want to convert it to '2020-09-19'.

I have tried this but it's not working:

```
select convert(varchar, '19-09-2020', 23)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify the source format for convert:

```
 convert(date, '19-09-2020',105)
```

This results in a DATE, if you actually want a VarChar again (of course, you shouldn't):

```
convert(varchar(10), convert(date, '19-09-2020',105), 23)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want string functions?

```
select concat_ws('-', right(mycol, 4), substring(mycol, 4, 2), left(mycol, 2))
from mytable
```

On the other hand, if you want to generate a `date` from that string, then:

```
select convert(date, mycol, 105) 
from mytable
```

Comment: I want to convert it to date and tried your suggest query but its giving below errors.  
select convert(date,[EXPIRY_DAT]) from [dbo].[RNFUNDEDTI] 
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.